# what does it mean to have momentum suppressed cross section

Tags: astrophysics, cosmology, dark-matter, cosmic-microwave-background, high-energy-astrophysics

What does it mean to have **momentum suppressed cross section and zero momentum transference** in direct and indirect detection of dark matter

Comment: Probably when a Weakly interacting massive particle collides with a Scintillator a gamma-ray photon is produced and based on the momentum suppressed cross section we can get the amplitude of the photon